# Slow SFTP/SCP/SSH speeds, but only in Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, sftp, scp

I have a pretty weird issue where all my downloads over SCP/SFTP/SSH seem capped at 1.3-1.5 MB/s. This is on a system where I speedtest ~500 Mbit/s downstream, so I expect something around 30-50 MB/s. Here's what I tried:

- Downloading from another remote server. Same issue, despite two different data centers and Linux distributions.
- Tried Filezilla, WinSCP and `scp` from within Ubuntu in WSL locally. They all exhibit the same issue.
- Issue persisted across two routers locally.

What's weird is that this issue seems to disappear when I actually boot Linux on my PC, so I have reason to believe it's somehow contained to Windows on my machine. Other types of downloads (HTTP and torrents) work fine and are not affected by this issue.

Does anyone recognize this and have any idea what could cause this to happen?

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default or do you have some sort of network intercepting or monitoring software installed?